# PHP places weird characters in my output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to generate a SQL based on some inputs . I have a predefined SQL(in which i do some replacements) which will consume these inputs to generate the required SQL using ODBC connection

I have stored the predefined SQL in a JS file for now .

Here is the code for the same :

```
function get_Result($query_passed){
    //echo "inPHP";
      $conn=odbc_connect(connectiondetails) or die(odbc_errormsg());
      $resultset = odbc_exec($conn, $query_passed);

    $rowValues = [];

    while(odbc_fetch_array($resultset)){
        $rowValue = odbc_result($resultset,1);
        array_push($rowValues,$rowValue);
    }

    echo $rowValues[1].$rowValues[2]; // for debugging purpose
    odbc_close($conn); // closing the connection
}
```

suppose the input is column1,column3
The required SQL which has to be generated is :

`Select column1,sum(l1+week*column3)+ ........sum(l175+week*column3) from tempTable`

my JS code looks like :

```
$.ajax({
        url: "logic/GetResultSet.php",
        type: "post",
        data:"query_To_Fire="+finQuery+"&action=get_Result",
        success: function(data){
    $("#finaleQuery").append("<b>Generated Query:</b>"+data);}
```

while debugging the JS i am getting the output as

```
select column1,sum(l1+week*column3)+...+sum(l76+week*column3)+LCLT_F3)1)����ȏ���ȏ 11 and so on
```

***The weird characters also include some text later which has various details like my ajax call parameters , my passwords etc .***

there won't be a problem if my input is column1,column2 is cos , there won't be any summation on column2

this has been bugging me since long . Any idea for this behaviour .

Note : I am working with sublime text so no option of debuggin the actual PHP code .

Comment: You are aware about that JS code can be modified by the user and that you will give users the possibility to use SQL-injections in your server by sending any modified query? You should generate a logical filter and escape/validate the user-input instead and please build queries server-sided only.

Comment: thanks @Steini , I was not fully aware of SQL injections. still the JS code i specified was just for testing purpose . I will build the queries on server side . 
but right now i was more concerned about the unwanted characters  in output & some missing output !

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the issue .

**PHP has a default setting of "4096" bytes for handling of LONG Fields . As mentioned [here](http://php.net/manual/en/odbc.configuration.php#ini.uodbc.defaultlrl)**

overriding the setting works for me : `ini_set("odbc.defaultlrl", "10K");`

`php.ini` can be modified to support project specific settings :

```
odbc.defaultlrl=4096 //default in php.ini
```

**useful note** :

```
; Handling of LONG fields.  Returns number of bytes to variables.  0 means
; passthru.
odbc.defaultlrl=0 //to get as many characters as the long text contains.
```